# Double integration using Gauss-Legendre quadrature

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I want to use Gauss-Legendre quadrature to evaluate a double integral. I came up with the following code

```
m=5000;

%generate weights and abscissas
[wx,xx]=leg(-1,1,m);
[wy,xy]=leg(-1,1,m);

%define function
psi=@(x,y) hypergeom(-1./4,3./2,x.^2.*y.^6);


%integrate with respect to x
intx=zeros(1,m);
for num=1:m
    intx(num)=sum(wx.*psi(xx,yx(num)));
end

sum(wy.*intx)
```

I use the notation leg(x1, x2, m) to generate the weights and abscissas.

Is there any other way to make this code run faster?

Comment: Why don't you define the psi outside the for-loop? But still this shouldn't be your bottleneck. Did you tried profiling your code? You can access it through the button "Run and time"

Comment: When i put psi outside the for lopp an error occurs. It says that the vatiable y is undefined

Comment: tried your suggestion however the code still runs very slow

Comment: might get more help asking such questions over at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: I really appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that w is a row vector you can use meshgrid to replicate y , x and then matrix multiplication:

```
m = 5000;
[w,x]=leg(-1,1,m);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x);
psi=@(x,y) hypergeom(-1./4,3./2,x.^2.*y.^6);
result = w * psi(X,Y) * w';
```

Comment: thanks! additional question: what if i have different limits? the first from -1 to 1 and the second from 1 to 3?

Comment: remains as an exercise for you :-). but as a guidance you can write meshgrid as meshgrdi(xx,yy) and you have wx and wy